# Flutter error : Unresolved package dexterous

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am currently trying to use flutter local notifications.
To do this, we need to use flutter_local_notifications package.

I am unable to add it as a receiver in my Manifest.xml file and the error that keeps popping up is : Unresolved package dexterous.

[image]

Also, when I check my flutter plugins,

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Would you mind posting your error stack?

Comment: It just says unresolved package. I don't know what you mean by error stack.